Laravel 11 delete item with Axios - how to redirect to error page after response
RoleController.php:
public function delete($id): string
    {
        $data = [
        'id' => $id
    ];

    return response()->json($data, 200);
}

app.js:
    form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
        event.preventDefault();console.log(url);

        axios.delete(url, {
            data: {
                id: id,
            },
        }).then(response => {
            if (response.status === 200) {
                let data = response.data;
                console.log(data);  // <- How do I redirect here?
            }
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error.message);
        });
    });
}

So, I get some response from the controller through axios. If the error checking and handling was done in the controller, I could use a redirect() or abort() or whatever. But as the error handling needs to be done in JS after receiving the response, how can I do the same from JS:
return redirect()->route('roles.index')->with('error', __('Role deleted'));

or

abort(403, __('SUPER ADMIN ROLE CAN NOT BE DELETED'));


You have to redirect using "window.location.href" function
Like
var redirectUrl = 'path of the page you want to redirect' inside this condition
if (response.status === 200) {
    let data = response.data;
    console.log(data);  // <- How do I redirect here?
    window.location.href = redirectUrl;
}


How would I pass a string to that page from JS?

Create the variable "redirectUrl" on the blade file above your app.js file is include. Like this "var redirectUrl= "{!! route('send-otp.user-account') !!}";" inside script tag
